Difference between localectl and LANG environment variable
My default language was set to en_IN. Then I came across update-locale and localectl to change my locale to support UTF-8. I changed it using
sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_IN.UTF-8

However that did not change LANG environment variable. But I could see the changes in /etc/default/locale.
I restarted my terminal. LANG is not set in .bashrc, .bash_profile either.

did you re-login? Or just restart a terminal?

No I did not as there was nothing in .bashrc or .bash_profile. But after logging in, the environment variable is reflected. I can not find on google about what files are loaded upon GUI login. Can you please point me there?

Sorry for late comment, on ubuntu for example this is done by systemd when starting the user session.
